# Rails translation displaying translation name in front of translation string in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, internationalization, translation

In my locale file, there is the following translation:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: "Die E-Mail Adresse wird bereits benutzt."
```

When i open the desired page in my browser, the error message looks like the following:

```
Email Die E-Mail Adresse wird bereits benutzt.
```

So does anybody know why there is another "Email" in front of the translated string?

Comment: Can you show what you're using on the view? It will help to understand what's happening.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to tell: it's a problem with devise i think.

Comment: `= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    =devise_error_messages!`

Comment: when i call another translation with t(".example"), it's working right as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct yml structure should be:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Dude
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "mail"
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one:   "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
          other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
      body: "There were problems with the following fields:"

  errors:
    format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
    messages:
      taken: "Email Die E-Mail Adresse wird bereits benutzt."
```

Note that there are two "errors" keys, one inside activerecord and another one outside. Use the later for validation messages.

You could get a more full detailed translation file from https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml

You might find the devise translation file at https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views/blob/master/locales/en.yml

For my projects, I usually have several translation files for each language:

- rails.en.yml: messages used by rails (inspired by the svenfuchs file)
- devise.en.yml: messages related to authentication (from the devise project itself)
- en.yml: messages I create on my views that doesn't belong to other gems (gems like "simple_form" usually have also their own file)

**Edit**

From the [Rails Internationalization guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models), validation messages will be searched in this order:

- activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank
- activerecord.errors.models.user.blank
- activerecord.errors.messages.blank
- errors.attributes.name.blank
- errors.messages.blank

So it's correct to use what you posted on the question:

```
de:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: "http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models"
```

Comment: I've read more carefully the rails guide on internationalization and it's possible another approach. I'll edit the answet to reflect that.